# Задать размер конкретного столбца таблицы grid с помощью CSS

Tags: css, grid

Итак, есть таблица построенная с помощью элемента CSS - grid

Есть свойство nth-child() - которое позволяет задавать конкретные параметры для дочерних элементов.

Что я хочу: я хочу, чтобы некоторые столбцы (например, 3 и 7) моей таблицы были меньшей ширины, чем остальные столбцы таблицы. Можно ли это сделать как-то с помощью элемента nth-child() в CSS или других аналогичных методов и не создавать кучу контейнеров с отдельными таблицами и параметрами для них?

```
.battle {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 800px;
  width: 1200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 9%);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 19%);
  gap: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1em 1%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 5%) 17% repeat(3, 9%) 14% 9% 9%;
}

div {
  height: 2em;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: спасибо. То что надо!